# Plotting a grid on a surfaceplot?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I am trying to make a grid on the surface of my surfaceplot, now I know that wireframe does not work and the grid command is something else entirely. But how do you plot things with grids like this? [image]

Here is the plot command I am using

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection="3d")

plot = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, shade=True,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the (second) example in the [matplotlib surface plot documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), from which the image in the OP comes from (see the [source code here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.py)), it is clear that the `plot_surface` function draws grid lines on surface plots by default. However, the plotting command

```
plot = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, shade=True,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

sets the width of the grid lines to zero, so they are not visible, but are present, when using this call. Remove the `linewidth=0` argument or set this to a value greater than 0.

Comment: Ok I feel stupid for not seeing that! But as a additional question, is it possible to make the grids larger? because the one I have now draws bold lines and really small grids (I tried playing with the linewidth)

Comment: the linewidth argument for me makes the grid lines thicker. What do you mean by *larger* grids? Perhaps you could post another question with some screen shots describing your problem.

Comment: Well, what I am getting now is this: http://imgur.com/fVz7a and I would prefer something more like http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/KleinBottle-02.png

Comment: I guess you mean the spacing between the grid lines. This is what the `rstride` and `cstride` arguments are for.

Comment: That just turns it into abstract art. :P

Comment: It's cool, but not completely what I want. http://i.imgur.com/QVJV0.png
Though I could try to persue an art career xD

Comment: @Coolcrab This has turned into a whole separate question, and the place to answer this is not in the comments to another answer. Please post another question. Alternatively, we can discuss exactly what you are trying to achieve in chat.